How to Log in to a Discord Bot with SOCKS5 Proxy Authentication
I am trying to log in to a Discord bot using a SOCKS5 proxy with authentication. Here is the simple code I am using to log in without the proxy:
import discord

TOKEN = "YOUR_BOT_TOKEN"


class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f"Logged in as {self.user}")


client = MyClient()
client.run(TOKEN)


How can I modify this code to use a SOCKS5 proxy with authentication (username and password)?
I tried to log in my Discord bot with this code but need to add SOCKS5 proxy with auth.
